# Is there anything like a Java Comparable interface in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop

Is there anything like a Java Comparable interface in Objective-C?

P.S. I need something like Comparable.compareTo() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html):

> If you need to compare whether one object represents a greater or lesser value than another object, you can’t use the standard C comparison operators > and <. Instead, the basic Foundation types, like NSNumber, NSString and NSDate, provide a compare: method:

```
if ([someDate compare:anotherDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // someDate is earlier than anotherDate
}
```